# How to batch multiple get request in SharePoint REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I'm trying to retrieve list items from SharePoint online list using multiple filter conditions (in power automate). Since the number of conditions is too large URL length was exceeding. I'm trying to use batch to sent multiple get requests in a single query. Below is how the entire query looks like in the flow body (send an http request to SharePoint action)

```
--batch_133
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
GET https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=(EmployeeEmail eq 'user1@gmail.com') HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata

GET https://site.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listName')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=(EmployeeEmail eq 'user2@gmail.com') HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata

--batch_133
```

The action is executed successfully and I received the results. But only the last query is working. Only results from the final get query is returned.

Any insights on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Arent you missing definition of `Content-type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` for the second one? based on this MS documentation [Make batch requests with the REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis#example-requests-and-responses)

Comment: Hi @Popkornak, Thank you for the suggestion. But when I add Content-type and Content-Transfer-Encoding, I'm receiving below error:

The request line 'Content-Type: application/http' is invalid. The request line at the start of each operation must be of the format 'HttpMethod RequestUrl HttpVersion'.
clientRequestId: 61529e53-a14b-4c9c-b605-056f4240805a
serviceRequestId: cdbeb3a0-6089-3000-971c-e2345a6110bc

any suggestions?

Comment: I referred the guide document you shared and updated the body of the request. It ran successfully but only returned outputs of one query. Is it not supported to batch queries to same list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing start of the second request `--batch_133` and headers `Content-type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding`

Answer:

```
--batch_133
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://<<TENANTHERE>>.sharepoint.com/sites/Site123/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('CustomList')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=(EmployeeEmail eq 'user1@gmail.com') HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata

--batch_133
Content-Type: application/http
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

GET https://<<TENANTHERE>>.sharepoint.com/sites/Site123/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('CustomList')/items?$select=Id,Title&$filter=(EmployeeEmail eq 'user2@gmail.com') HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata=nometadata

--batch_133
```